# ffmpeg install specific version Fedora 21

Tags: ffmpeg, fedora, downgrade

I have a webapp working in local, but failing on the server. Both use Fedora 21.
I need to check if the ffmpeg configuration of my server (2.4.11 instead of 2.4.10) is to blame.

On server, a simple print() of the ffmpeg command displays an array, while on local it displays a string.

In the code, I call:

```
pipe = sp.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdout = DEVNULL, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=fp)
```

then:

```
pipe.stdin.write(....)
```

On server, last line fails with message "Broken Pipe Error"
and ffmpeg error: "pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you specifically need 2.4.10?

Comment: I have a webapp working in local, but not on the server, with only the ffmpeg commands failing.

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue? There is not enough info here for us to provide much help.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry the issue may depend on several aspects of my app. i succeeded in updating the ffmpeg versions to do several tests, and now I suggest it's a difference of ffmpegwrapper version.

Comment: I've never heard of "ffmpegwrapper".

Comment: https://github.com/interru/ffmpegwrapper It turns out this was the source of our problem :) I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem did not come from ffmpeg, but from ffmpegwrapper.
https://github.com/interru/ffmpegwrapper

The clue was that a simple print of the ffmpeg command was not formatted the same on both machines.
On the server, I installed the same version than I used in local, and now it's running fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Fedora 21 is EOL so the repositories are gone and you should upgrade to current release.

Also `ffmpeg` is not in official repositories, but unofficial are also [gone](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/29619405/dir/fedora_21/com/ffmpeg-2.4.10-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm.html). You would need to find the source and probably build if from source.

Comment: I feared that :(
I've updated my question with more details. I have a perfectly working webapp launching ffmpeg commands, and those same commands fail on server. I'd like to have the same configuration there.